# How can I constant storybook url when I change CSF file name of file path?

Tags: storybook, zeplin

I am linking storybook with zeplin, but whenever I change CSF file name of file path, the storybook url will be changed, cause the linked broken.

How can I constant the storybook url.
I am using storybook version 7 within nextjs.

Thanks.